# Match a line in a text file containing two keywords

Tags: sed, grep

Sample file

```
ssdnaslcnasjkdlcnljaksjcnaslcnlasncadcadsoadsklfjewilfm Warning error ascacs
kjasdncijojencikmasklcmioewmnconmqewciomnweiocn warning
sakcjnaksldnmclkasdmnckljamnklckmalc aslenkjlansdcledlkamsc error
alscmkklamclkamscklmnaeuye error warning
```

I just want to fetch the lines that have both "error" and "warning".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Case sensitive:

```
sed '/warning/!d; /error/!d' < file
```

or

```
awk '/warning/ && /error/' < file
```

or

```
grep warning < file | grep error
```

### case insensitive:

#### GNU

```
sed '/warning/I!d; /error/I!d' < file
```

```
gawk -v IGNORECASE=1 '/warning/ && /error/' < file
```

#### standard

```
grep -i warning < file | grep -i error
```

```
awk '{l = tolower($0)}; l ~ /warning/ && l ~ /error/' < file
```

```
sed '/[wW][aA][rR][nN][iI][nN][gG]/!d; /[eE][rR][rR][oO][rR]/!d' < file
```

(that one having the advantage that it's not dependendant on the locale; other ones could fail to match on WARNING and match on WARNİNG instead in some locales for instance).

Comment: The sample input may require case-insensitive search.

Comment: @Bodo, good point. I've added a case insensitive variant.

Comment: Is the `<` redirection really needed?

Comment: @Jetchisel, not really, but it generally helps. Another way to put it is that passing the file name as argument is not needed as here the shell can open the file itself (and not run `sed`/`awk`/`grep` if it can't be open and give more useful and consistent error messages in scripts, and doesn't fail with weird file names, and can be but anywhere on the command line, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Another, simpler approach to this problem: `grep -Ei 'error.warning|warning.error'`

Comment: Wouldn't that assume that these two words are only ever separated by exactly one letter? Perhaps a `.+` would be more general here (or even ` .*` to have at least one space).

Comment: Yes, it would. It's just a very simple alternative, tailored exactly to the example above. This won't work for a more general approach (see the excepted answer aobve).